# How to fix touch disabled when removing subview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have main storyboard and it adds the view from another `UIViewController` in the storyboard onto it as a subview because i want a method to modally present another view using a timer.

I can add the subview (from the second `UIViewController`)  but when i hit close, the `UIView` gets removed but I can't click anywhere.

To display second storyboard view:

```
 UIViewController* controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MemberViewController"];

 [viewController addChildViewController:controller];

 controller.view.frame = controller.view.bounds;

 [viewController.view addSubview:controller.view];

 [controller didMoveToParentViewController:viewController];
```

To hide the subview

```
+ (void)hideContentController: (UIViewController *) content
{
    [content willMoveToParentViewController:nil]; // 1
    [content.view removeFromSuperview]; // 2
    [content removeFromParentViewController]; // 3
}
```

**Both the above blocks of code are in a `NSObject`**

And i have a close button in the second storyboard view and its a `UIViewController` class that calls hideContentController in the `NSObject` file once the close button is hit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try commenting lines 1 and 3 in the hide function and try! Just removing the `UIView` normally does the trick for me!

Comment: didn't work unfortunately ..

Comment: Does the `UIViewController` you are trying to add as a subview have any `UIGestureRecognizers` that take up the whole view?

Comment: i have not added any ui gesture recognizers.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it like below:

Create `IBOutlet` `@property` of `btnClose` button in `MemberViewController.h`

Take `MemberViewController* controller` class variable in your implementation of `SecondViewController.m` class:

```
//Write in your SecondViewController.m
controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MemberViewController"];
 [controller.btnClose addTarget:self action:@selector(closeAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubView: controller.view];

//Close Action method
-(void)closeAction()
{
 [controller.view removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Comment: i get this 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController btnClose]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11a08f000'

Comment: Try to fix this issue.. me to having look in this.

Comment: Do no connect Selector from storyboard of btnClose

Comment: so where do  put it?

Comment: also do i connect btn close property outlet in member storyboard to the button?

Comment: In storyboard just connect outlet for btnClose not its selector. I want to know what u did with btnClose ?

Comment: okay so in member storyboard view i connected the btnclose outlet to the close button on the interface.

Comment: next inside the NSOBJECT FILE i added   MemberViewController* controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MemberViewController"];
                    
                    
                    
                    [controller.btnClose addTarget:self action:@selector(closeAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                    [viewController.view addSubview:controller.view];

Comment: can you please share you closeAction method here

Comment: here is the close action method  i added in the same NSOBJECT FILE as the last code i posted...

Comment: [self.view addSubView:controller.view];

Comment: -(void)closeAction:(id)sender {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"secondstoryboard"
                                                         bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]];

    MemberViewController* controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MemberViewController"];
    [controller.view removeFromSuperview];
}

Comment: It should not be added in NSObject class

Comment: [self.view addSubView:controller.view];   doesn't work cuz its in a nsobject file...

Comment: where do i put the close action then?

Comment: Add it on your view controller where you are adding this MemberVC

Comment: i need my add subview called in nsobject class

Comment: I'm adding the member vc via nsobject class

Comment: But it should be viewcontroller... then try passing reference of ur VC to NSObject class

Comment: how so?   cause i m sure i did.. i passed it to my nsobject hence [ThePassedviewController.view addSubview:controller.view]

Comment: Update your question in brief i will look into this.

Comment: Hii ASH is you issue fixed? i dont know why are u using NSObject class because as of my point of view you should not follow such approch.

Comment: fixed i had made a mistake somewhere.